# Silverlight Combobox showing only one item

Tags: c#, silverlight, combobox

I am adding items to a combobox from a string array but I can only see one item. Please help:
xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboHostels" Margin="12,15,44,5" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="30"/>
```

C#:

```
public Hostel()
        {
InitializeComponent();
cboHostels.ItemsSource = new string[] {"HOSTEL1", "HOSTEL2"};
}
```

At runtime, the combobox displays only the first item. Anything I need to do?

Comment: Ditto. Out of curiousity, your class declaration doesn't implement Window/UserControl/etc. Is your question code copy/pasted, or is it possible there's something missing?

Comment: @goobering Which class declaration? I only see a constructor calling InitializeComponent, which makes it very probable that class Hostel is a UserControl.

Comment: Ignore me / daft previous comment / brainfart.